# Debian freezes when not used. Suspend failure?

Tags: linux, debian, screensaver, suspend, acpi

When I leave my Debian/Xfce laptop alone for a while the screen turns black and then it is stuck there.

Nothing happens when I press a key or move the mouse, the screen stays black. I can however press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f123</kbd> to get to another tty and it is not black, but I cannot get back to X11. I have to restart the computer, e.g. with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

How do you prevent this from happening?

I have disabled power saving in the Xfce/Gnome settings manager, I have disabled the screensaver there, and I have disabled DPMS. There is nothing written to `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` or `/var/log/pm-powersave.log`, and I do not see a relevant entry in syslog/dmesg.

Comment: try `xset s off`

Comment: That seems to help